# Typescript how to assign generics to generic variable field

Tags: javascript, generics, typescript

How do I correctly assign a generic class field to a generic local field?

For example I have this generic interface implemented in a generic class

```
export interface TableBoxProps<T> {
   getDataSource: <T> () => T[];
}

class Container<T> extends React.Component<TableBoxProps<T>, any>{ ... }
```

and somewhere I have a function where I want to get an entry from the datasource e.g. like this

```
 private onCellClick = (row: number, column: number) => {
      let entity:T = this.props.getDataSource()[row]; // error
   }
```

I get the error with the above

```
[ts] Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'
```

What do I have to change that I can use `let entity:T`? It works fine with the type `any`, but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused because `this.props.getDataSource()[row]` is of type `{}`. You need to cast it to T:

```
let entity: T = (this.props.getDataSource()[row] as T);
```

You need to use `as T` rather than `<T>` because you are using React with JSX.

Comment: Thx. Since I am using ReactJs I had to cast it with `this.props.getDataSource()[row] as T`.

Comment: But can you explain why I have to cast it to `T` when I am in the generic class anyways?

Comment: Please show your class definition - it may be in there

Comment: @MuratK. I have updated my answer. Please accept it if it has helped you.

Comment: This is actually only a workaround that hides the actual problem which I've described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57400076/1660584 .

Comment: @amik thanks for your answer, I've voted to delete mine.

Comment: In TypeScript 4.3, this is not valid syntax:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAuGAVGBeGAKA3gXxgEMI0BKAbiA

Comment: but, if T is defined in a class it would be. nevermind

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of `TableBoxProps<T>` is wrong. In `getDataSource: <T> () => T[];`, the `<T>` shouldn't be here as it declares another generic type `T` that shadows the `TableBoxProps<T>`. You actually declared a generic function in a generic interface.

What you have written is equal to:

```
export interface TableBoxProps<T1> {
   getDataSource: <T2> () => T2[];
}
```

And correct solution should be

```
export interface TableBoxProps<T> {
   getDataSource: () => T[];
}
```

Comment: is this expression
export interface TableBoxProps<T1> { getDataSource<T2>: () => T2[]; }
equal to this expression?
export interface TableBoxProps<T1> { getDataSource: <T2> () => T2[]; }

Comment: @ArelSapir nope, the first one is not even valid code. Interface members cannot be generic, they may only contain a generic function.